# Printing every line of the CSV file using readlines()

Tags: python, csv, readline

I am trying to print each line of a csv file with a count of the line being printed.

```
with open('Polly re-records.csv', 'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:   #file1 path
    ct=0
    while True:
        ct+=1
        if file.readline():
            print(file.readline(),ct)
        else:
            break    #break when reaching empty line
```

for the above code i am getting the following output:

```
lg1_1,"Now lets play a game. In this game, you need to find the odd one out.",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
 479
sc_2_1,Youve also learned the strong wordsigns and know how to use them as wordsigns. ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
 480
```

so instead of the ct starting from 1,in my output the first value is directly 479 which cant be possible unless the if statement is executed 478 times

what changes should i do or what is the logical flaw preventing the print statement from executing

Comment: Why don't you add appropriate `print` lines and see what the code is doing yourself?  Otherwise, provide a [mcve] and input file that cause the exact output you describe, so we can run it for ourselves.

Comment: readline() or readlines()?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to leverage some of baked in python methods like `enumerate()`

```py
with open("Polly re-records.csv", "r") as file_in:
    for row_number, row in enumerate(file_in, start=1):
        print(row_number, row.strip("\n"))
```

With respect to what you might change and keep your code, the issue you are running into is you are calling `readline()` too often and discarding half the results.

```py
with open('Polly re-records.csv', 'r',encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:   #file1 path
    ct=0
    while True:
        ct+=1
        row = file_in.readline().strip()
        if row:
            print(row, ct)
        else:
            break    #break when reaching empty line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", 'r') as file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    header = next(csvreader)
    for x in range(len(csvreader)):
        print(csvreader[x], x)
```

Else you can also use other methods as enumerate

Answer (score 0):

Python offers useful built-in functions for your use-case. For example [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), which yields a consecutive count for each item in an iterable.

```
with open('Polly re-records.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(file):
        print(line, line_number)
```

As drdalle noted, it might also be a better idea to use the built-in [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) as it will also handle csv encodings (e.g. if you have multi-line cells containing `\n` wrapped or other escaped values.